# Grab SOAP request on localhost

Tags: wcf, soap, proxy, fiddler

I have the same Service1 service running on localhost and public: `http://calculator.gear.host/Service1.svc` `http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/mex`.

I would like to grab packets for testing purposes using Fiddler. As client acts `WcfTestClient.exe` application with configuration inside

```
`WcfTestClient.exe.config` that asks wcf client go through proxy.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy
              bypassonlocal="false" 
              proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888"              
              />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
  <runtime>
    <DisableMSIPeek enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Everything goes fine with `calculator.gear.host`, but I cant see packets in Fiddler using localhost or 10.1.2.112 (my ethernet IP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to telerik you need to use the machine name rather than localhost or the IP:

http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Observe-Traffic/Troubleshooting/NoTrafficToLocalhost